# How to Run Admin functions on Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create a function to delete all users from the Database and write it on index.ts file and deploy it. Now, how can I run it?? I don't want my clients to run it from their mobile app, I need some admin tool to run the management functions. When I see cloud functions on Firebase console there's no option to run the functions, just to view their logs.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions isn't for running one-time scripts.  You should do that on your local machine.  Cloud Functions is for running code that responds to HTTP requests, or events that occur within other products in your project.

Comment: Exactly, but how do I run it on my local machine? What does firebase recommend?

Comment: Firebase doesn't recommend anything.  Do whatever you have to do to make that happen.  Just run the node process on the command line if it works for you.

Comment: But how do I run the command line?? Let's say my command is- exports.accountcleanup = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this article: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html - it suggests using App Engine cron job for that purpose. Relevant project on github: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/functions-cron

Also there's an example on similar topic in Firebase docs: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron